# In mongoDB Fetch array element at a position which is also present in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-aggregation

I am using mongoose for connecting mongodb in node.js, now i have a document schema as given below

```
var ArraySchema = new Schema({
     array: [{type: String}],
     counter: {type: 'Number', required: true}
});
```

Now i want to fetch **array element** whose position is **counter** which is present in the document as well, i read many questions like this on SO and on most of them i found mongoose aggregation but i don't know how to use aggregation to solve my problem.

If anyone of you have used aggregation please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query in my mongoose.

```
var aggregation = [
{
  $project : {
    array :  {$arrayElemAt: [ "$array", "$counter" ] }  
    }
}]
db.collectionName.aggregate(aggregation).exec(function(err, model){
if(err){
// handle error}
console.log(model);
})
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with this query:

```
db.pos.aggregate([
   {
      $project:{
         result:{
            $arrayElemAt:[
               "$array",
               "$counter"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```